# How to remove data on file processing in C?

Tags: c, file

I'm writing a program that handles data like the following:

```
  Player Name     | Average Score   | Number of Playing
=======================================================
  Andi            | 88              | 5
  Joko            | 49              | 2
  Tono            | 56              | 3
  Ani             | 15              | 7
  Banghe          | 87              | 1
  Ferdinand       | 99              | 1
```

And allows users to choose from the following options at the terminal:

1. View Record
2. Add Player Record
3. Add New Player
4. Delete Player
5. Save and Exit

When I enter function number four the name should be removed from the list. Here's an example of this process:

```
Score Record DotA Player
========================
1.View Record
2.Add Player Record
3.Add New Player
4.Delete Player
5.Save and Exit

Input your choice[1..5]: 4

Input player name [1..10 kar]: Tono

Tono successfully deleted..

Press Enter to continue....
```

After that, function 1 should display the data as follows, with an item deleted:

```
  Player Name     | Average Score   | Number of Playing
=======================================================
  Andi            | 88              | 5
  Joko            | 49              | 2
  Ani             | 15              | 7
  Banghe          | 87              | 1
  Ferdinand       | 99              | 1
```

Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

const int Max = 100;

FILE *team;
int i = 0;
int score[Max];
int numberofplaying[Max];
char nama[Max][40];
int jumlah;

void menu()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("Score Record Dota2 Player\n");
    printf("========================\n");
    printf("1.View Record\n");
    printf("2.Add Player Record\n");
    printf("3.Add New Player\n");
    printf("4.Delete Player\n");
    printf("5.Save and Exit\n");
    printf("\nInput your choice[1..5]: ");
}

void bacaData()
{
    int i = 0;

    team = fopen("Dota2.txt", "r");
    if (team == NULL)
    {
        printf("<<EMPTY RECORD>>");
    }
    else{
        while (fscanf(team, "%s %d %d", nama[i], &score[i], &numberofplaying[i]) != EOF)
        {
            i++;
        }
        jumlah = i;
    }
    fclose(team);
}

void writeData()
{
    printf(" Player Name | Average Score | Number of Playing\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 49; i++)
    {
        printf("=");
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < jumlah; i++)
    {
        printf("\n%s | %d | %d", nama[i], score[i], numberofplaying[i]);
    }


    printf("\n\nPress Enter to continue.....");
}

void addData()
{
    printf("Input player name[1..%d] : ", jumlah);
    scanf("%s", nama[jumlah]);
    fflush(stdin);
}

void insertData()
{
    int i;
    team = fopen("Dota2.txt", "w");
    for (i = 0; i < jumlah; i++)
    {
        fprintf(team, "%s %d %d\n", nama[i], score[i], numberofplaying[i]);
    }
    fclose(team);
}

void insertDataScore()
{
    int i;
    team = fopen("Dota2.txt", "w");
    for (i = 0; i < jumlah; i++)
    {
        fprintf(team, "%d\n", score[i]);
    }
    fclose(team);
}

void deleteData()
{
    team = fopen("Dota2.txt", "w");
    for (int j = strlen(nama[jumlah]); j < jumlah; j++)
    {
        strcpy(nama[i], nama[i - 1]);
        score[i] = score[i - 1];
        numberofplaying[i] = numberofplaying[i - 1];
    }

    fclose(team);
}

int main()
{
    int choice = 0;
    do
    {
        bacaData();
        do
        {
            menu();
            scanf("%d", &choice);
            fflush(stdin);
        } while (choice < 1 || choice > 5);
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            system("cls");
            for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            {
                printf("\n");
            }
            writeData();
            getchar();
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("\n");
            addData();
            printf("Input player score[0..100] : ");
            scanf("%d", &score[jumlah]);
            score[jumlah]++;
            insertDataScore();
            printf("Score successfully updated^^");
            printf("\n\nPress Enter to continue.....");
            insertData();
            getchar();
            break;
        case 3:
            printf("\n");
            addData();
            jumlah++;
            printf("\nData successfully added..");
            printf("\n\nPress Enter to continue.....");
            insertData();
            getchar();
            break;
        case 4:
            printf("\n");
            addData();
            deleteData();
            printf("\n%s successfully deleted..", nama[jumlah]);
            jumlah--;
            printf("\n\nPress Enter to continue.....");
            getchar();
            break;
        }
    } while (choice != 5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Jarod42: Looks like valid C++ to me.

Comment: @Jarod42 umm yeah this is C code but i use C++ for make it.. sorry.. i'll edited my tittle.. i can't.. i'm still learning from the basic..

Comment: If you compile it as C++ then call it C++, that's fine.

Comment: @BenVoigt: As I understand, OP cannot use C++ stuff. (but he compiles anyway with c++ compiler for convenience).

Comment: i use Visual Studio 2013 ultimate for compile this code.. so what do you think it's C code or C++ code? @BenVoigt

Comment: Depends on the file ending. Is it .cpp or .c ?

Comment: it's .cpp that why i use C++ on my tittle..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need a `findIndexPlayer(const char* name)`

```
int findIndexPlayer(const char* name)
{
    for (int i = 0; i != jumlah; ++i) {
        if (strcmp(name, nama[i]) == 0) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1; // Not found
}

void askPlayerName(char* name)
{
    printf("Input player name[1..40 kar]");
    scanf("%s", name);
    fflush(stdin);
}
```

then

```
void deletePlayer(const char* name)
{
    const int indexPlayer = findIndexPlayer(name);

    if (indexPlayer == -1) {
        // You may display error message.
        return; // Player not found in record
    }
    for (int i = indexPlayer; i + 1 < jumlah; i++)
    {
        strcpy(nama[i], nama[i + 1]);
        score[i] = score[i + 1];
        numberofplaying[i] = numberofplaying[i + 1];
    }
    --jumlah;
}
```

then

```
    case 4: {
        char playerName[40];
        printf("\n");
        askPlayerName(playerName);
        deletePlayer(playerName);
        printf("\n%s successfully deleted..", playerName);
        printf("\n\nPress Enter to continue.....");
        getchar();
        break;
    }
```

Note that I have not save the result in file.
It may be done in a separated function.

Note:
You have other bugs in your code.

Style Notes:
globals scope may be reduced, that means, move declaration where there are needed only.

```
FILE *team;
int i = 0;
```

Comment: okayy thank you for ur help.. i'm still doesn't understand lol.. but i'll try it.. thanks a lot..

Comment: sorry if i ask too much but could u see.. variable jumlah is integer i can't be use for strcmp.. @Jarod42

Comment: @Monstrowcity: it was a typo, it should be `name`. fixed now.

Comment: it's still didn't work -__- did u build this with filling struct or not?? cause it think this is not like filling struct

Comment: @Monstrowcity: My modified code is here http://ideone.com/WRcPJ4 (I don't succeed to make input works into ideone, but work in interactive mode for me).

Comment: your code is make the data itself erased after i stop the compile time.. what's happen??@Jarod42

Comment: FILE *team = fopen("Dota2.txt", "w"); these your code's bug.. just use append for it.. but it's okayy i can fix it.. thank you very much for everything.. now i understand my problem.. @Jarod42

Answer (score 0):

Your case 4 is both adding and deleting data, which probably cancel each other out and do nothing.

Comment: i think it's not... case 3 is adding.. case 4 deleting data by choose one data for delete it from list.. @Ben Voigt

Comment: @Monstrowcity: I'm not looking at your description, I'm looking at the actual code you posted, which has `case 4:` then `addData(); deleteData();`

Comment: ohh okay.. so could u give me a direction for making case 4?? @BenVoigt

Comment: but wait addData(); it's not actually adding data.. could u see the function addData(); before u help me?? @BenVoigt

Comment: Then it has the wrong name. Anyway, your delete Data has variable j for the loop but never uses it. And what does strlen have to do with anything. You can't compare length of one name to number of names, yet that is what j does.

Comment: lol.. come on it's just a function i make it like that so i can use it much more easier.. i think variable i is already use for everything before.. so i think i'll make another variable for looping.. because the input from deleting is choosing by their name that's why i'm stuck..